# Kotlin Micronaut is not loading application.yml properties

Tags: kotlin, configuration, micronaut

After following `5. Team Configuration with @ConfigurationProperties` in this document https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-configuration-maven-kotlin.html. And created a configuration bean like this

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: sftp-test
netty:
  default:
    allocator:
      max-order: 3
sftp:
  known-hosts-file: "testKnownHost"
  private-key-file: "testPk"
  username: "testUser"
  password:
  remote-host: "1.0.0.0"
  remote-port: 22
  verify-timeout: 20000
```

```
// SftpConfig.kt
@ConfigurationProperties("sftp")
class SftpConfig {
    var knownHostFile: String = FileConverterConstant.SFTP_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE_PATH
    var privateKeyFile: String = FileConverterConstant.SFTP_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH
    var privateKeyPass: CharArray = FileConverterConstant.SFTP_PRIVATE_KEY_PASS.toCharArray()

    @NotBlank
    lateinit var username: String

    @NotBlank
    lateinit var remoteHost: String
    var remotePort: Int = FileConverterConstant.SFTP_REMOTE_PORT
    var verifyTimeout: Long = FileConverterConstant.SFTP_VERIFY_TIMEOUT
}
```

```
// Inside a test function
    "Test" {
        val items: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        items["sftp.username"] = "test"
        items["sftp.remoteHost"] = "1.0.0.0"

        val ctx = ApplicationContext.run(items)
        val sftpConfig = ctx.getBean(SftpConfig::class.java)
        println(sftpConfig.username)
    }
```

If I remove the properties from the items map for example `items["sftp.username"] = "test"`, the missing properties was filled with the properties from the application.yml file I configured. Everything seems to be working in the test like this page documented.

So now I moved this to an Singleton bean class
When I use `@Inject` like below to create the bean and try to use the bean. It wont read anything from the application.ym

```
@Inject
val sftpConfig = SftpConfig()
```

Now it gives me this error message `Message: lateinit property username has not been initialized` If I allow the filed to be null. It is null after calling the bean. So the values in application.yml file is not being loaded at all.

While in the test the ApplicationContext was manually created, in here I am relying on Micronaut, am I missing certain dependency? What could be the reason the values in application.yml is not loaded? Side note, if I assign a health endpoint in the application.yml file, it does work after server starts. So the file is being read, but the values I configured for sftp is not being injected in to the configuration bean.

Comment: I can't see that `lateinit`is used in the example you've linked to. We're using `var` with default value like in your example link, and that should work. BR

Comment: The example works fine since that was manually creating the application context and assigning values to them, if I do not assign the value there, it was taking the value from the application.yml file which was what I wanted to do.

Comment: But when I use `@Inject` in a bean and then simply trying to print the sftpConfig values(e.g. `println("USERNAME====${sftpConfig.username}")`). it was giving me that error message. If I remove the `lateinit` and give it an default value, it uses the default value with no errors, but I would like it to pick up the application.yml file value if it is configured, and use the default value if it is not configured in the yml file.

Comment: Could the problem be the way Micronaut runs? In the linked example using application context to get the bean, it works perfectly fine with the yml file values. But when I run the Micronaut app, is it not running the application context? And here is the main method.
```fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    run(*args)
}```

Answer (score 1):

For testing your config, you should use `@MicronautTest` and inject the config-DTO like shown below.

```
import io.kotest.assertions.assertSoftly
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.BehaviorSpec
import io.kotest.matchers.string.shouldNotBeEmpty
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.kotest5.annotation.MicronautTest

@MicronautTest
class SftpConfigPropertiesTest(sut: SftpConfig) : BehaviorSpec({

    Given("populated sftp in application.yml") {
        Then("all fields should be populated") {
            assertSoftly(sut){
                it.username.shouldNotBeEmpty()
                /** add remaining assertions */
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I believe best practice is to use constructor injection instead of `@Inject`. Example:

```
@Singleton
class MyService(private val sftpConfig : SftpConfig) {

  /** class body goes here */
}
```

Comment: This actually worked, I am new to Micronaut, do you mind explain when should we be using @Injected and why in this case it is not loading the application.yml file values at all? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Glad to hear it worked. We're having a lot of Micronaut-apps, and we're not using @Injected except for when setting up abstract test-specs. If you add the complete code for your test, I'll be able to pin-point the problem in more details. I guess your test is not starting the MN-environment, that is what `@MicronautTest` does. BR

Comment: @TechNoob Please let me know if my answer needs more info. BR